# Django Forms and Formset edit

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I am trying to create a edit fbv but my edit is not saving up.

```
views.py

def editplayform(request,id):
    play = Play.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = forms.PlayForm(request.POST, instance=play)
        time_shown_formset = forms.TimeShownFormSet(request.POST, instance=play)
        if form.is_valid() and time_shown_formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            time_shown_formset.save()
            return redirect("play:home")
    else:
        form = forms.PlayForm(instance=play)
        time_shown_formset = forms.TimeShownFormSet(instance=play)
    return render(request, 'play/fbvplayform.html', context={'form':form, "time_shown_formset":time_shown_formset, 'play':play})
```

```
edit.html
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h1>Edit PLAY</h1>
  <div>{{ form.non_form_errors }} {{ form.as_p }}</div>
  <h1>Edit Timeshown</h1>
  <!-- prettier-ignore -->
  {{ time_shown_formset.non_form_errors }} 
  {{ time_shown_formset.management_form}} 
  {% for form in time_shown_formset %}
  <div>{{ form.times.label }}: {{ form.times }}</div>
  {% if time_shown_formset.can_delete %}
  <div>{{ form.DELETE }} {{ form.DELETE.label }}</div>
  {% endif %} {% endfor %}
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Update Play</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

It is returning POST response on the terminal but the edit is not saving and its not returning to home.html.

What am i doing wrong please?

Comment: Do you want to change this entry: Play.objects.get(id=id)? And show us your forms. Also, instead of: forms.PlayForm(...) use: PlayForm(...) and also for another form.

Comment: The form is validating and getting submitted if it's not Formset, i am having issues with editing my formsets inputs.